# How do i add progressbar to track the upload of FTP

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp

I am currently working on FTP type of program that can send lots of files at the same time and i managed to find some old code that worked for it i edited it alot thought. Anyways i am kinda still learning and i tried to get the progressbar to work but i could not so, whats wrong with my code:

```
  Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim hInet As Int32 = InternetOpen("nn:", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
    Dim hFtpSession As IntPtr = InternetConnect(hInet, "IPADDRESS", 21, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", 1, 0, 0)
    For Each f As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(FlatTextBox1.Text + "Files\")
        Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(f)
        FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, f, fi.Name, 0, 0)
    Next
    Dim fileStream() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FlatTextBox1.Text + "Files\")
    Dim requestStream As System.IO.Stream = hInet.GetRequestStream() ' Here is my first issue.
    For offset As Integer = 0 To fileStream.Length Step 1024
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CType(offset * ProgressBar1.Maximum / fileStream.Length, Integer))
        Dim chSize As Integer = fileStream.Length - offset
        If chSize > 1024 Then chSize = 1024
        requestStream.Write(fileStream, offset, chSize)
    Next
    InternetCloseHandle(hInet)
    FlatAlertBox1.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error...`  *but i could not so* doesnt quite get there

Comment: @Plutonix Hey, Sorry i forgot to mention but when i debug the code and upload the file it doesnt affect the progressbar value.

Comment: did you set `WorkerReportsProgress` to true?

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah i tried that but it did not change anything i think that next after   FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, f, fi.Name, 0, 0) does this but i dont know what do.

Comment: Your progress goes from 0..1 instead of 0..100.  Multiply by 100.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the sub **BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged**, you could instead somehow get the speed of upload (how long it takes to upload 1 kilobyte, megabyte, etc.) and use a timer to increment the progress bar using the information. When the program starts, just have it upload a small file and record how long it takes to upload. Or you could do it just before you start uploading. This way, you wont have to rely on the **BackgroundWorker1.ProgrssChanged** changed, and as a plus, you can implement an estimated time for upload.

Comment: Hope you realize that my internet speed isnt the same as someone else so recording the upload would be stupid.

Comment: How? The upload will begin when the program is started, a timer could then record the time it took using it as a variable throughout the rest of the  program

Comment: Ok i'll try to make one (this one will download instead of upload, but the core idea is the same) I'll post a link when i'm done.

Comment: Ok i'm done, here's the link: [link](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8rm16r72uf1jfaz/Download_ProgressBar.zip?dl=0)  It doesn't have the progress bar but has the general code which can be used in you program. Click KBS to get the estimated download time of the main file.